# DRF: Djoser override custom user serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, djoser

Previously I had been working with the back-end, but after few months of not coding, I'm now not really comfortable with the code I have now. So I use Djoser and I have this in my project **settings.py** file

```
  ...
    'SERIALIZERS': {
            'user_create': 'backend.accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
            'user': 'backend.accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
            'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
  ...
```

This should override the default Djoser serializer, but as I can see it does nothing.

**/auth/users/me/** - Returns this

```
{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "id": 1,
    "username": "test"
}
```

but I have this as my serializer inside **backend/accounts/serializers**

```
class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    delete_request = DeleteUserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'email',
            'username',
            'password',
            'delete_request',
        )
```

Why does it not override?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/users/me/` endpoint is handled by `current_user` key in djoser serializers dict, so you should add it:

```py
'SERIALIZERS': {
    # [...]
    'current_user': 'backend.accounts.serializers.UserSerializer',
    # [...]
}
```

You can have more information about [djoser serializers on the documentation](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#serializers).

They say:

> Key 'user' is used for general users whereas 'current_user' lets you set serializer for special /users/me endpoint. They both default to the same serializer though.

And by the way I think you should create a serializer inheriting from `djoser.serializers.UserSerializer` and not from `djoser.serializers.UserCreateSerializer` for `user` and `cuttent_user` keys.